# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError haystack: cannot import name force_text

Tags: django-haystack

Please find packages which I installed

```
pip freeze
```

### akismet==0.2.0 BeautifulSoup==3.2.0 bleach==1.2 cmsplugin-feed==0.1a4 Django==1.3.7 django-activity-stream==0.6.1 django-admin-tools==0.4.1 django-appconf==0.4.1 django-blog-zinnia==0.16.dev0 django-classy-tags==0.3.4.1 django-cms==3.3.0.dev2 django-cms-anchor-plugins==0.0.1 django-compressor==1.1.1 django-debug-cache-panel==0.0.1 django-debug-toolbar==0.9.1 django-debug-toolbar-user-panel==0.1 django-excel-response==1.0 django-extensions==0.6 django-filer==0.8.7 django-filter==0.5.3 django-form-designer==0.1a6 django-formwizard==1.0 django-graceful-session-cleanup==0.2.2 django-groups==0.1.dev11 django-haystack==1.1.0 django-honeypot==0.3.0 django-html-sanitizer==0.1.4 django-indexer==0.2.1 django-jsonfield==0.7.1 django-memcache-status==1.1 django-mptt==0.4.2 django-notifications-hq==1.0 django-pagination==1.0.7 django-paging==0.2.2 django-picklefield==0.2.0 django-polymorphic==0.2 django-registration-redux==1.4a0 django-reversion==1.5.7 django-sekizai==0.4.2 django-sentry==1.4.1 django-seo-link==0.1.3b0 django-simple-captcha==0.3.4 django-tables==0.3.dev0 django-tagging==0.3.1 django-templatetag-sugar==0.1 django-test-utils==0.3 django-uni-form==0.9.0 django-voting==0.1 django-wakawaka===0.4.dev1dev docutils==0.7 dojango==0.4.7 easy-thumbnails==1.0a16 feedparser==4.1 html5lib==0.95 johnny-cache==0.3.3 markdown2==2.1.0 memcache-toolbar==0.5.5 MySQL-python==1.2.5 openpyxl==1.8.4 pycountry==1.20 Pygments==1.3.1 pygooglechart==0.4.0 pyprof2calltree==1.1.0 python-dateutil==2.4.2 pythonmemcached==1.57 pytz==2015.7 simplejson==2.2.1 six==1.10.0 South==0.7.6 Sphinx==1.0.3 tablib==0.9.11 versiontools==1.8 Whoosh==1.3.3 xlwt==0.7.3

Answer (score 0):

force_text is nowhere to be found in the django-haystack v1.1 repository on github

try uninstalling and reinstalling

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall django-haystack==1.1.0
```